# Meta Reputation Points

Tags: discussion, meta

I've read from other questions the the Meta Reputation points that you earn do not effect your gaming.stackexchange.com account.  That's fine, but I am curious.  Do the **positive** meta points serve any point at all?  Are they accumulated toward any privileges?  Or are they just part of the Stack Exchange "plumbing" and were, therefore, never removed from the Meta system?

Comment: Points aren't useful on meta because up/down votes on questions and answers here are usually given [based on agreement/disagreement with the sentiment](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/a/3757/2259), not because of the "usefulness" of the post.

Answer (score 5):

Nope. Your meta score is equal to your score on the main site, +/- a bit if there's been a really recent change (the meta score doesn't update instantaneously).

You *can* get meta badges on Meta, but you won't get any sort of rep (up *or* down) that's not from your parent user on Gaming.

Answer (score 4):

The only thing you don't get from receiving votes is the points.  They don't affect your score, so they don't affect your privileges.  They *do*, however, count toward badges.